# Can I market a legal food product with the name of an illicit drug or other illegal product?

Tags: trademark, advertisements, food, drugs

Say I've reverse-engineered the Coca-Cola formula, or produced something very similar in taste. Since the recipe is not patented, I can sell my product so long as I don't market it as Coke, Coca-Cola, etc. Say this formula is deemed safe and has been approved by the FDA and any other regulatory body. In particular, it does not include cocaine.

Would I be allowed to market this product as "Cocaine cola" or "Cocaine soda?" To sidestep the potential trademark issue, could I name an independently conceived product after a drug? Going a step beyond saying it's "like crack" and instead saying naming a brand of potato chips "edible meth" or similar?

Edit: Specifically would there be a problem when marketing food?

Comment: Isn’t there a perfume called Opium ? And at least one song called Heroin ?

Comment: The perfume I was not privy to, but the song I think would be regulated differently since there's no reasonable way someone could get confused about a song containing drugs.

Comment: https://www.yslbeautyus.com/fragrance/womens-fragrances/opium/

Answer (score 4):

**Would I be allowed to market this product as "Cocaine cola" or "Cocaine soda?"**

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Possibly not if you were to try and register the name, as this may well fall foul of [s.3(3)(a), Trademarks Act 1994](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1994/26/section/3?timeline=false) which says:

> A trade mark shall not be registered if it is—
>
> - (a) contrary to public policy or to accepted principles of morality...

The government's [Manual of Trade Marks Practice](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/trade-marks-manual/the-examination-guide), at section 5.8, explains that:

> Marks which **may be** ‘contrary to public policy’ are those, for example, that make specific references to illegal drugs such as cocaine... (*my emphasis*)

Comment: This restricts what trademarks can be registered but could I still market the product as such without a registered mark?

Comment: The Supreme Court has just about blow that provision up. They ok’ed Slants for a band  made up of Asian guys and FUCT as a name if a shirt.